# How to HTTP Respond (Response Structure)

Tags: java, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm writing an HTTP API for a server that reads and parses requests (using Java).

After processing the requests, I need to send information back but I'm unclear on the structure of an HTTP response and/or if Java has anything in-built in that regard to help.

Here's the HTTP response structure I've tried using but the curl (request) command on the client-end complains about *Empty reply from server*.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 \r
Content-Type: text/plain \r
Connection: close \r
\r
<Some body text or rather the data to respond with>
\r
```

Note: There are newlines following the carriage returns.

I'm try to send the data using a PrintWriter which is attached to the socket's output stream. When I don't print the above response at all and just close the PrintWriter, I still get the same reply.

After using PrintWriter.print(...), PrintWriter.flush() and PrintWriter.close(), nothing arrives at the client-end. Am I missing something? Is something wrong with the structure I am choosing or the way I am choosing to send the response?

Comment: It should be `\r\n` instead of `\r`, _thanks dear ms for that EOL thing_.

Comment: Try `-vvv` curl flags to show verbose output while debugging.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you may want to take a look at the HTTPServer included in the JDK. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html